# Wall-Sliding, Stuck at Corners

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am having trouble with my 2-D wall-sliding.  Namely, when the player avatar collides with the wall, it "snaps" to the corner (see screenshot, below) and sticks there.  The red, transparent rectangle is my "wall":

[image]

My code is as follows:

"FootRectangle" is your standard xna rectangle. Location is a vector2.  The player is moving to a target, which could be anywhere on the screen, which is also a vector2.

```
 if (wall.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(player.FootRectangle))
            {


                // collision above block
                if (player.FootRectangle.Top <= wall.CollisionRectangle.Top)
                {
                    player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, wall.CollisionRectangle.Top - player.FootRectangle.Height / 2);
                }

                // collision below block
                else if (player.FootRectangle.Bottom >= wall.CollisionRectangle.Bottom)
                {
                    //player.FootRectangle.Y = block.CollisionRectangle.Bottom;
                    player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, wall.CollisionRectangle.Bottom + player.FootRectangle.Height / 2);
                }

                // collision left of block
                if (player.FootRectangle.Left <= wall.CollisionRectangle.Left)
                {
                    player.Location = new Vector2(wall.CollisionRectangle.Left - player.FootRectangle.Width / 2, player.Location.Y);
                }

                // collision right of block
                else if (player.FootRectangle.Right >= wall.CollisionRectangle.Right)
                {
                    player.Location = new Vector2(wall.CollisionRectangle.Right + player.FootRectangle.Width / 2, player.Location.Y);
                }
```

How can I resolve these collisions so that the avatar snaps to a corner and smoothly makes his way to the target destnation?

I attempted to implement a similar solution to that at [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82640/wall-sliding-collision-response-only-works-on-one-axis-2d); however, it seemed to stick when the collision occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking some inspiration from Aj_'s answer, I was able to resolve the collision successfully with the following code:

I found that I needed to test for both:
`wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y) * rectRatio > wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X`

and

`wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y > wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X`, etc.

Otherwise, the player's foot rectangle would still clip through the corners of the wall rectangle (varied, depending on which test was omitted.

```
                // check for collision
                if (wall.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(player.FootRectangle))
                {
                    // set collision offset
                    int collisionOffset = 4;

                    // find height/width ratio for wall rectangle
                    float rectRatio = wall.CollisionRectangle.Width / wall.CollisionRectangle.Height;

                    // resolve collision from top and right
                    if ((wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y) * rectRatio > wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X ||
                        wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y > wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X)
                    {
                        // right
                        if (player.FootRectangle.Left >= wall.CollisionRectangle.Right - collisionOffset)
                        {
                            player.Location = new Vector2(wall.CollisionRectangle.Right + player.FootRectangle.Width / 2, player.Location.Y);
                        }

                        // top
                        if (player.FootRectangle.Bottom <= wall.CollisionRectangle.Top + collisionOffset)
                        {
                            player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, wall.CollisionRectangle.Top - player.FootRectangle.Height / 2);
                        }
                    }

                    // resolve collision from left and bottom
                    if (wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X > (wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y) * rectRatio ||
                        player.CollisionRectangle.Center.X - player.FootRectangle.Center.X > wall.CollisionRectangle.Center.Y - player.FootRectangle.Center.Y)
                    {
                        // bottom
                        if (player.FootRectangle.Top >= wall.CollisionRectangle.Bottom - collisionOffset)
                        {
                            player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, wall.CollisionRectangle.Bottom + player.FootRectangle.Height / 2);
                        }

                        // left
                        if (player.FootRectangle.Right <= wall.CollisionRectangle.Left + collisionOffset)
                        {
                            player.Location = new Vector2(wall.CollisionRectangle.Left - player.FootRectangle.Width / 2, player.Location.Y);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The only type of collision that this code doesn't resolve if when the player's foot rectangle hits directly on the corner.  I will update this answer, when I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself these questions: Does your player get stuck on contact? Does your player on contact 'jitters' more into the wall and then gets stuck, or does your player get stuck when moving or jumping fast into the wall.

If it gets smoothly stuck on contact, you need to improve your guard. Are you absolutely sure that the distance between center of your player and the edge of your foot is `FootRectangle.Width / 2` ? Try changing your inequality to > and < instead of >= and <=. Or offset your player a little bit more by one pixel or an easy way out, something like (0.51*player.FootRectangle.Width).

If your player jitters into the wall, the other thing that I can think of when looking at your code is maybe you got the signs of the direction of the velocity vector mixed up. Check if it jitters into the wall. If yes, check that  going left is indeed defined by a negative sign (and going up with a positive) as you otherwise move the player more into the wall. Change swap then + and - accordingly when before `FootRectangle.Width / 2`.

(Btw. the way I do resolve stuck collisions is by storing the last known position before the collision and resetting the scene and implement the collision response if this response does not lead to being stuck again (forward check); otherwise set the velocity to the direction of the offset vector.)

Comment: Any idea how to do this in JS with meshes of all sides ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518457/javascript-wall-collision-on-convex-shapes-getting-stuck-at-corner

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you meant by 'stuck'. If it's stuck as in 'can't move in any direction' then the problem probably in the offset distance.

Are `FootRectangle.Height`, `FootRectangle.Width, Location.x, Location.y` etc.  of type `float` or  `int` ? If it's an `int` then dividing it them by 2 (which another `int`) will only yield an `int`. Meaning, something like 3/2 will give you 1 instead of 1.5. Thus messing up your offsetting.

You should use `float` versions of `Rectangle` and `Location` to fix this. Or if your `Location` is of type `float` then you could cast those variables to `float` before doing any operations. Like,

```
player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, (float)wall.CollisionRectangle.Top - (float)player.FootRectangle.Height / 2f);
```

If it's getting 'stuck', or rather 'hit', when you try to move up then it's behaving as expected because `Rectangle.Intersects()` is returning true. This means a really small area of your `FootRectangle`is overlapping the `wall.CollisionRectangle`. If you want to disregard this minor overlap and proceed as if nothing happened, you could use a modified version of `Rectangle.Intersects()`or add some small extra offset to the new location.

```
float smallOffset = .1f;

player.Location = new Vector2(player.Location.X, wall.CollisionRectangle.Top - (player.FootRectangle.Height / 2 + smallOffset) );
```

Remember this would only work if `Location` and `Rectangle` contain `float` variables.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean with 'stuck' but have a look at [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109812/platformer-collision-problems/110199#110199). I shared my simple 2d collision system. Maybe it helps. :)